# How to split array name in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working on a laravel webservice, my code is the following

```php
public function getLanguageshow(){

    $user_id=$_REQUEST['user_id'];

    $profiles="SELECT * FROM `abserve_language_details` as `le` where `le`.`user_id`=".$user_id;
    $details=\DB::SELECT($profiles);

    $prof = \DB::table('abserve_proficiency')->select('*')->get();

    $vals = explode(',', $details[0]->lan_proficiency);

    foreach ($prof as $key => $value) {
        if(in_array($value->id, $vals))
            $lang_prof[] = $value->name;
    }

    $lang_prof = implode(',', $lang_prof);

    foreach ($details as $key => $value) {
        $value->lang_prof = $lang_prof;
    }

    $response['language_details'] = $details;

    echo json_encode($response);exit;
}
```

and my result is

```php
{
    "language_details":[
        {
           "id":12,
           "user_id":121,
           "languages":"Tamil,English,Chinese,Bulgarian,Amharic,Fiji",
           "lan_proficiency":"1,5,4,3,2,4",
           "read":"1,1,1,1,1,1",
           "write":"1,1,1,1,1,1",
           "speak":"1,1,1,1,1,1",
           "lang_prof":"elementary,limited_working,professional_working,full_professional,native_or_bilingual"
       }
    ]
}
```

In this result `lan_proficiency` have 6 ids (1,5,4,3,2,4) but that id name ("lang_prof":"elementary,limited_working,professional_working,full_professional,native_or_bilingual") displays 5 names only 4 is repeated

I want result

```php
{
    "language_details":[
      {
        "id":12,
        "user_id":121,
        "languages":"Tamil,English,Chinese,Bulgarian,Amharic,Fiji",
        "lan_proficiency":"1,5,4,3,2,4",
        "read":"1,1,1,1,1,1",
        "write":"1,1,1,1,1,1",
        "speak":"1,1,1,1,1,1",
        "lang_prof":"elementary,limited_working,professional_working,full_professional,native_or_bilingual,full_professional"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I read it twice but don't get what you need. `lan_proficency` are both identical.

Comment: sry my mistake actual result is

Comment: actual result is       {"language_details":[{"id":12,"user_id":121,"languages":"Tamil,English,Chinese,Bulgarian,Amharic,Fiji","lang_prof":"1,5,4,3,2,4","read":"1,1,1,1,1,1","write":"1,1,1,1,1,1","speak":"1,1,1,1,1,1","lan_proficiency":"elementary,limited_working,professional_working,full_professional,native_or_bilingual"}]}

Comment: but i want                              {"language_details":[{"id":12,"user_id":121,"languages":"Tamil,English,Chinese,Bulgarian,Amharic,Fiji","lang_prof":"1,5,4,3,2,4","read":"1,1,1,1,1,1","write":"1,1,1,1,1,1","speak":"1,1,1,1,1,1","lan_proficiency":"elementary,limited_working,professional_working,full_professional,native_or_bilingual,full_professional"}]}